# How to do automation testing after click of button?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Is there any way to do automation testing after click of button. For e.x: I have opened the app and then on click of button it should open another app and fill the form.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make a loop for waiting as you click the event. Look on this tutorial, maybe will be helpfull for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbOxrOZHCko
If it's the same application on your mobile I guess this is also possible with the Android operation, you should check it in the specification.